# Matomo - Location provider plugin and access to visit details

Tags: plugins, matomo, location-provider

i trying write my first Matomo plugi n(Location provider) that will determine user's location based on custom dimension column.

So far I have came up with this code:

```
<?php

namespace Piwik\Plugins\LocationProviderCustom\LocationProvider;

use Piwik\Plugins\UserCountry\LocationProvider;

class CountryProvider extends LocationProvider {

public function getLocation($info) {

    // custom_dimension_1 should be accessible here

    $location = array(
        self::COUNTRY_CODE_KEY => 'us'
    );
    self::completeLocationResult($location);
    return $location;
}

public function isWorking() {
    return true;
}

public function isAvailable() {
    return true;
}

public function getSupportedLocationInfo() {
    return array(
        self::COUNTRY_CODE_KEY => true
    );
}

public function getInfo() {
    return array(
        'id' => 'locationProviderCustom',
        'title' => 'Location Provide',
        'description' => '',
        'order' => 5
    );
}

}
```

So in getLocation($info) I should determine the country code. 
$info is holding just IP address and browser language.
All of location provider plugings that I saw used one of those two properties to determine user's country.

Is it possible to get visit details and especially custom visit dimension values into the Location provide? Or should I approach it some other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Common::getrequestVar()](https://developer.matomo.org/api-reference/Piwik/Common#getrequestvar) to get the request values.

Here's an example where I was using custom variable rather than custom dimensions:

```
    public function getLocation($info)
    {
        $country_code = 'us';

        $_cvar = Common::getRequestVar('_cvar', '{}');

        //in my case $_cvar string looks something like '{&quot;1&quot;:[&quot;COUNTRY&quot;,&quot;gb&quot;]}'

        $_cvar = html_entity_decode($_cvar);
        $decoded_cvars = json_decode($_cvar, true);

        if ($decoded_cvars !== NULL) {
          $custom_var = array();

          foreach($decoded_cvars as $var) {
            $custom_var[$var[0]] = $var[1];
          }

          if (array_key_exists('COUNTRY', $custom_var)) {
            $country_code = $custom_var['COUNTRY'];
          }
        }

        $location = array(
          self::COUNTRY_CODE_KEY => $country_code
        );

        self::completeLocationResult($location);

        return $location;
    }
```